# DNS zone change from 1st hosting to 2nd, time of update?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

Can't get an idea, why this strange situation caused to happen:
There is a domain in RU zone with NS records that lead to 1st hosting provider,
I've managed to change this NS zone to another 2nd hosting provider. The domain is successfully delegated, but when i'm trying to reach URL, it leads to 1st hosting provider NS records.

What time does it need to change NS records for domain globally ?

Any ideas ?!

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your domain name, this is hard to answer.  This is mainly because the parent domain controls this, overall.  org, net, and com happen fairly fast, as do info and several other TLDs.  Some, however, only publish once or twice a day, so it could vary widely.

For future changes, I highly recommend doing NS record changes with these procedures:

If you can, serve the data from the old and new hosting companies.  This ensures things won't break during the transition.  You should keep the old site up for at least the TTL period of the longest TTL in your zone.  Both new and old should serve as close to the same data as you can, and the NS records should point ONLY to the new servers.

If you cannot keep the DNS servers up on both locations it is harder and you will have an outage.  To control how long that is:

1. Set the TTL on your NS records to something small, like 300.
2. Wait until the previous TTL has expired.  If you used 3600, an hour.  If it's longer, you should expect to wait that long.

At this point, you've done the best you can.  Point the NS records from your parent zone to your new ones (through your registrar interface probably.)  If you have both new+old running, you should get no outage.  If you had to do it the hard way, you will get an outage of about the TTL period for new lookups until the NS records expire AND your parent updates their servers.

Answer (score 0):

"What time does it need to change NS records for domain globally ?"

It's all about the TTL set on that record, as others have said. It's not a guarantee but is generally reliable in my experience.

Answer (score -2):

It's safe to say around 24 hours, assuming everything is configured properly.

You could try running `ipconfig /flushdns` in a command prompt if you're using Windows and then try it again.

Comment: Thanks, hope this idea is the true answer for upper question. Let's wait :)

Comment: Hardly safe to say that at all. More like a week, as an increasing number of systems just ignore the TTL and cache it for extended periods.

Comment: -1. This answer is at best, a guess, and is also incorrect. The correct answer relates to the TTL of the records in question. As John notes, some DNS servers may ignore the TTL, but in most cases the TTL alone determines the lifetime of the records in any DNS client cache.